# Issue with applying dotted border to cells in table design

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/84/

In this screenshot, the green lines represent where I'm trying to apply dotted lines.

[image]

I am able to get the left-right borders to appear as dotted lines, but not the bottom borders.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: ok, i tried kingjiv's suggestion below, and made some headway with the left/right border, but having issue with the bottom borders so revising question.

Comment: thanks for the answers everyone...unfortunately only can select one, but your diversity of solutions should be good educational material for other readers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to the rules of conflict resolution when it comes to border collapse.  Solid takes precedence over dotted:

http://lachy.id.au/dev/css/tests/bordercollapse/bordercollapse.html

I believe you will need to make the conflicting borders dotted as well.  So if you went a cell's left border to be dotted, you'll need to make the right border of the cell to its left also dotted (or anything of lower precedence, but dotted make the most sense).

Comment: @keruilin, the same applies to the top/bottom borders. The same way you changed your fiddle to work with the left border works with the bottom.  If you need the bottom dotted then the cell below needs to have a dotted top border.  See the bottom border of `vlah` in the first table http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/103/ .  I simply made the top border of `clah` dotted.

Comment: Sweet link, demonstrates border conflict resolution very well

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution:

1. If you do not specify the four borders for each cell, but only the left and bottom borders, you will **avoid border conflicts:**

   ```
   .geniusPicks table tr.pickConsensusBody td {
       border-left: solid 1px black;
       border-bottom: solid 1px black;
       background: grey;
   }
   .geniusPicks table tr.pickBody td {
       border-left: solid 1px black;
       border-bottom: solid 1px black;
   }
   ```
2. Then, to make the dotted borders in the fourth column you just have to apply your `dottedLeftBorder` and `dottedBottomBorder` classes to its cells (but only the `dottedLeftBorder` class for the last cell).

Now here is the corresponding fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fvds5/3/, where every cell in the fourth column has now left and bottom dotted 1px black borders, except the last one that has no dotted bottom border.

Comment: +1 Nice, that does the trick. But a little confused. Isn't the [separated borders model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders) supposed to be the default?

Comment: @NGLN Yes, it's the default model; but after reading the previous answers and comments on this page I first thought the collapse border model was used in the question.

Comment: @NGLN @Luc, in the example the collapse is coming from the "Normalized CSS" that is checked off.  The normalization css has `border-collapse:collapse;`

Comment: @kingjiv Aaah, thanks! I will turn off that feature in future.

Comment: I don't know if anyone else noticed this, but in Google Chrome, the 'plah' row has a solid border on the left, the other rows are fine though...  It's really weird, if I highlight 'plah' from left to right, it goes away... Does anyone else experience this?

Comment: @whoabackoff I've corrected this now, it was due to something I had forgotten to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this answer is partially devised from the information provided in the previous answers, but simply adding `!important`, or making both left- and right- borders dotted of adjacent cells is not enough.

First, the rendering mechanism between various browsers is not the same. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/gFA4p/99/) shows two lines over the total height of 4 rows in IE, FF and Opera. But Chrome and SafariWin shorten the left line to only one row.

To compensate for this, I added an extra dummy column, which proved also very usefull to eliminate most of the classes in the HTML.

Secondly, the base css style now only gives a left- and bottom-border to the cells. As a result, the last cells got a `lastCol` style, because IE7 does not add borders to the `tr` tag.

Here is the [revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/102/), tested with IE7, IE8, IE9, FF, Opera, SafariWin and Chrome.

**Edit:**

If you réally don't want the dummy column, I've managed it to get [this far](http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/100/), but that solution does not work in Chrome or SafariWin. *(Something strange is going on. Maybe someone else can explain.)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/109/

[image]

All I did was add

```
.dottedBottomBorder {
    border-top: none !important;
} 

.dottedRightBorder + .dottedBottomBorder {
    border-top: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

to the bottom of the style sheet, as well as add the `dottedBottomBorder` class the four cells on the right side of each pick column.

The problem you have is the bottom cell's solid border is overlapping the top cell's dotted border.  This alleviates that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.geniusPicks table tr.pickConsensusBody td {border:1px solid; background:grey;}
```

This is your problem. I would think you should assign separate classes to table cells instead of general assignments a la tr>td
Maybe there's a way with less hassle though, not sure. But basically that line overrides your dotted style.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's overwriting or ignoring your dotted borders in td. because you set the borders to solid here:

```
.geniusPicks table tr.pickConsensusBody td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

edit: someone beat my by ~20 seconds here...

Answer (score 0):

This works if I add inline styles to the HTML and get rid of the class names.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/xWSKD/1/

**EDIT**

This also works if I add the styles to the css with an `!important` declaration

```
.dottedRight{border-right:2px dotted black !important;}

.dottedBottom{border-bottom:2px dotted black !important;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/xWSKD/2/

**Note**

The fiddles show the dotted line as `red` only to point out the change.  See above code for correct use.

Also, see the comment below re implications of using `!important` ( [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) )

Comment: -1 Both solutions don't work with `1px dotted black`. As kingjiv already said: `2px` takes precedence over `1px`, just like `solid` over `dotted`.

Comment: @NGLN thanks.  Appreciate the distinction (but not the -1 ;-)  However, OP never said it needed to be `1px`.  As `2px dotted` is very similar in size to `1px solid` (see the fiddle above), this seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Ok, if you edit your answer and change red into black, then I remove the downvote. But remind: [What are the implications of using “!important” in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Comment: Thanks @whoabackoff.  That's why I added the note above: "The fiddles show the dotted line as red only to point out the change. See above code for correct use."

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works), you can:

- find all elements in that wanna-have-geen-borders column
- give them all dotted green lef
- give them all dotted bottom green border

  - use the :last to remove the undesired bottom border from the last element

You can find all rows in that column by doing something like:

```
$(td[class*="greenBorder"]).addClass("green_borders");
$(td[class*="greenBorder"]).last().css('border-bottom','')
```

Note im saying something like because im not very good with jQuery and don't have the right syntax/grasp of how selectors are used. But I've seen examples where similar things are done. You can find tonnes of examples of this site, or consult the original documentation (which is kinda bad, imho).

Ok, I did it:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Green Border</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .geniusPicks {}
    .geniusPicks table {width:100%; font-size:12px;}
    .geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading {border:0px solid; height:30px;}
    .geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading th {background:darkRed; color:white; font-weight:bold;}
    .geniusPicks table tr.pickHeading {border:0px solid;}
    .geniusPicks table tr.pickHeading td {background:red; padding-left:10px;}
    .geniusPicks table tr.pickConsensusBody td {border:1px solid; background:grey;}
    .geniusPicks table tr.pickBody td {border:1px solid;}
    .bigGap td {height:19px;}
    .smallGap td {height:10px;}
    .geniusPicks table th,
    .geniusPicks table th+th+th+th+th+th,
    .geniusPicks table .pickHeading+tr td,
    .geniusPicks table .pickHeading+tr td+td+td+td+td+td+td {text-align:center;}
    .geniusPicks table th+th+th,
    .geniusPicks table .pickHeading+tr td+td+td {text-align:left;}
    .borderLeftRadius {
        border-radius:15px 0 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius:15px 0 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius:15px 0 0 0;
        -khtml-border-radius:15px 0 0 0;
    }
    .borderRightRadius {
        border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
        -khtml-border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var green = jQuery("td[name='green']");
    green.each(function(){

        var cl = $(this).attr('class');
        var prev = $(this).prev();
        $(this)
            .css('border-color','#aeaeae')
            .css('border-style','dotted')
            .css('border-right-style','solid')
            .css('border-right-color','black')
            .addClass(function(i,currentClass){ return "dotted"; });

        if (prev.attr('class') == "dottedRightBorder") {
            prev.css('border-right-style','dotted')
                .css('border-right-color','#aeaeae')
        }

        if (cl=="top") {
            $(this)
                .css('border-top-style','solid')
                .css('border-top-color','black')
        } else 

        if (cl=="bottom"){
            $(this)
                .css('border-bottom-style','solid')
                .css('border-bottom-color','black')
        }
    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="geniusPicks">
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">

            <thead>
                <tr id="picksHeading">
                    <th class="borderLeftRadius">Sport</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Pick</th>
                    <th>Genius</th>
                    <th>Genius Credential</th>

                    <th class="borderRightRadius">Result</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="bigGap">
                    <td colspan="7"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickHeading">

                    <td colspan="7" class="borderLeftRadius">blah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickConsensusBody">
                    <td rowspan="4">moo</td>
                    <td rowspan="4">flah</td>
                    <td rowspan="4" class="dottedRightBorder">glah</td>
                    <td name="green" class="top">vlah</td>

                    <td>mlah</td>
                    <td>nlah</td>
                    <td rowspan="4">jlah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickConsensusBody">
                    <td name="green" >clah</td>
                    <td>dlah</td>

                    <td>xlah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickConsensusBody">
                    <td name="green" >plah</td>
                    <td>slah</td>
                    <td>klah</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="pickConsensusBody">
                    <td name="green" class="bottom">qlah</td>
                    <td>wlah</td>
                    <td>zlah</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="smallGap">
                    <td colspan="7"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr class="pickHeading">
                    <td colspan="7" class="borderLeftRadius">blah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickBody">
                    <td rowspan="4">moo</td>
                    <td rowspan="4">flah</td>

                    <td rowspan="4" class="dottedRightBorder">glah</td>
                    <td name="green" class="top">vlah</td>
                    <td>mlah</td>
                    <td>nlah</td>
                    <td rowspan="4">jlah</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="pickBody">
                    <td name="green" >clah</td>
                    <td>dlah</td>
                    <td>xlah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickBody">
                    <td name="green">plah</td>

                    <td>slah</td>
                    <td>klah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pickBody">
                    <td name="green" class="bottom">qlah</td>
                    <td>wlah</td>
                    <td>zlah</td>

                </tr>

                <tr class="smallGap">
                    <td colspan="7"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here we go http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/86/