# Safari bug in table with border dotted

Tags: html, css, safari

This is in Safari and Chrome:

[image: http://demx.info/files/rufanbook_basket.jpg]

**CSS:**

```
TABLE {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
TABLE TH,
TABLE TD {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted #898989;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
table th {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

But for more complex layouts where you can't disable border this easily, you could consider using the separate border model [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326266/issue-with-applying-dotted-border-to-cells-in-table-design) because the repetitive pixel pattern of *dotted* could get an offset (depending on the starting position) which could result in a solid line between adjacent cells.

Comment: Thanks, i'm remove border-collapse, add cellpadding and cellspacing (both 0), add border-right and bottom for each td, border-left for first cells each tr and border-top for table. That's work! :)

Comment: @demx I assume you use :first-child for that. Remind that the first `td` in a `tr` may not be situated in the first column if you use multiple rowspan.